# R: Dimension names in tables and multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, dataframe, type-conversion

Since a function that I use requires a table object as parameter, I would like to convert a multidimensional array to a table, but I have problems with dimension names.

As specified in the help file of `as.table`, the `dnn` parameter should contain dimnames names.

```
dnn … the names to be given to the dimensions in the result (the dimnames names).
```

But even when specifying `dnn`, my tables produced by `as.table` have no dimension names.

The following code illustrates my problem.

```
>test <- table(c("a","b","c","c","c"),c("1","2","3","2","2"),dnn=c("letters","numbers"))
>test 

          numbers
letters 1 2 3
      a 1 0 0
      b 0 1 0
      c 0 2 1

# this works perfectly
```

now try the same when constructing the table from an array:

```
>my2dimdata <- array(c(1,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1),dim=c(3,3),
                    dimnames=list(c("a","b","c"),
                                  c("1","2","3")))
>my2dimdata

  1 2 3
a 1 0 0
b 0 1 0
c 0 2 1

# the array as expected

>my2dimtable <- as.table(my2dimdata,dnn=c("letters","numbers"))
>my2dimtable

  1 2 3
a 1 0 0
b 0 1 0
c 0 2 1

# there are no dimnames
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`as.table` doesn't have a `dnn` argument. You need to set the dimnames manually.

```
my2dimdata <- array(c(1,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1),dim=c(3,3),
                    dimnames=list(c("a","b","c"),
                                  c("1","2","3")))

my2dimdata <- as.table(my2dimdata)
names(attributes(my2dimdata)$dimnames) <- c("letters","numbers")

#        numbers
# letters 1 2 3
#       a 1 0 0
#       b 0 1 0
#       c 0 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Note also that `names(attributes(my2dimdata)$dimnames)` correctly refers to those dimnames names in question, while `dimnames(my2dimdata)` is something entirely different.