# How to add label in table() in R

Tags: r

I want to print 2*2 confusion matrix and label it. I am using `table()` in r.

[image: Please click this to see the table]

I want to add predicted and Reality label . Can anybody suggest me , how can I do it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `table` returns an R object of class `"table"`, which is just an array of integers with some `attributes`. Are you asking how to layout/print a table? In that case the R packages `kable` and `stargazer` might be worth for you to take a look at.

Comment: You can also do it at the point of the table creation using named arguments - `table(var1 = 1:3, var2=1:3)`

Comment: And, to add to @thelatemail's comment, you can also use the "dnn" argument if your named arguments aren't what you wanted. Compare `table(data.frame(v1 = sample(c("pos", "neg"), 10, TRUE), v2 = sample(c("pos", "neg"), 10, TRUE)))` with `table(data.frame(v1 = sample(c("pos", "neg"), 10, TRUE), v2 = sample(c("pos", "neg"), 10, TRUE)), dnn = c("predict", "reality"))`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1:Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a similar problem to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754152/r-dimension-names-in-tables-and-multi-dimensional-arrays). You can follow that approach, 
but simplify things a bit by just using a matrix to hold the values, and 
just setting its dimension names to `"predicted"` and `"observed"`:

```
# create some fake data (2x2, since we're building a confusion matrix) 
dat <- matrix(data=runif(n=4, min=0, max=1), nrow=2, ncol=2, 
              dimnames=list(c("pos", "neg"), c("pos", "neg")))

# now set the names *of the dimensions* (not the row/colnames)
names(dimnames(dat)) <- c("predicted", "observed")

# and we get what we wanted
dat

# output: 
#             observed
#   predicted       pos       neg
#         pos 0.8736425 0.7987779
#         neg 0.2402080 0.6388741
```

*Update*: @thelatemail made the nice point in the comments that you can specify dimension names when creating tables. The same is true of matrices, except you supply them as names of the `dimnames` list elements when calling `matrix()`. So here's an even more compact way:

```
matrix(data=runif(n=4, min=0, max=1), nrow=2, ncol=2, 
       dimnames=list(predicted=c("pos", "neg"), observed=c("pos", "neg")))
```